# Adding style to affected values in shell sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, visualization, shellsort

I implemented shell sort algorithm to an application like this:

```
shell: function() {
    var list = anada.vars.$list;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = parseInt(list[i], 10);
    }
    var n = list.length;
    var increment = Math.floor(n / 2);
    var i;        

    while (increment > 0) {
        for (i = increment; i < n; i++) {
            var temp = list[i];
            var j = i;
            var affectedOne = j;
            var affectedTwo;
            while (j >= increment && list[j - increment] > temp) {
                list[j] = list[j - increment];
                j -= increment;
            }
            list[j] = temp;
            var rows = '<tr>';
            for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++) {
                if (counter > j - increment && counter < i + 1 && counter % increment == 0) {
                    rows += '<td class="affected">' + list[counter];
                } else {
                    rows += '<td>' + list[counter];
                }
            }
            anada.vars.$elements.push(rows);
        }
        increment = Math.floor(increment / 2);
        var row = '<tr>';
        $.each(list, function(n, val) {
            row += '<td class="iteration">' + val;
        });
        anada.vars.$elements.push(row);

    }
    $('.result-content').find('table').empty();
    $.each(anada.vars.$elements, function(n, val) {
        $('.result-content').find('table').append(val);
    });
    anada.vars.$elements = [];

},
```

the problem is like this:

1. The first part of the sorting highlights only '21', it must not highlight because, 15 and 21 did not change its position from the entry.. The list entry was
   15,14,0,34,2,44,21,6,7,12,5,34,20.

if index 0 is greater than index 7, which is half of the total number of the list + 1, they will change position,

this is the pairing:

first iteration: 
15-21,
14-6,
0-7,
34-12,
2-5,
44-34,
6-20

What i want to highlight are those only whose positions are changed.

[image: first part of the sorting]
[image: after some iterations, the ending part is like a insertion sort]

what is my mistake.

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to work the math. The value `i` represents the index where you started swapping elements backwards. The value `j` is where that element finally ended up, and `increment` represents the step size.

Consider an element at position `counter`. It was swapped with the element that moved if all of the following are true:

- `counter` is a number of steps forward from `j` that's a multiple of `increment`. In other words, `counter >= j && counter - j % increment == 0`.
- `counter` is not past the start point. In other words, `counter <= i`.
- At least one element moved. In other words, `i != j`.

Putting this together yields this condition:

```
if (i != j && counter <= i && counter >= j && counter - j % increment == 0) {
    // Element was swapped
} else {
    // Element was not swapped
}
```

The condition that you're checking is close to this one, but has some off-by-one errors and forgets to shift by `j` when doing the mod. Try this and see if that fixes things.